# How do I make console application run after clicking "ok" from mfc dialog box in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, merge, console-application

In my visual studio 2010 project, I included two solutions. I have an mfc application, which is a dialog box, and another visual c++ application that just prints out text. What I want to happen is for the dialog box to pop up, then the user will input x values, y values, etc, and once the user clicks okay the second application will do calculations on these variables and then give an output. I have the two projects made already, but I'm having trouble combining them. The first thing to pop up when the combined project runs is simply a dialog box, and once the user clicks ok, something that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/paooW.png should appear. Any help would be appreciated - sorry if my explanation was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Your picture is a console app. So you want to make sure your second app is created as a console app and accepts its inputs in the argc, argv command line.

The first app would call CreateProcess to start the second app, passing its path and its command line.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the response. Sorry for the potentially ignorant question, but where can I find the path and its command line? Sorry, I'm new to visual studio and usually work on a mac so I'm not as familiar with windows.

Comment: The "path" is the complete file name of the file you want to run.  It might be something like C:\Program Files\Company\Prog2.exe

The "command line" is a fundamental C paradigm, not Windows related. A console program starts at main, and main receives two parameters: argc and argv. They give the command line to the program. See any C or C++ textbook if you are not familiar with this interface.